# Data display issue in FlatList from Realm database

Tags: realm, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I have done inserting data into Realm database.

Now, After inserting the data to db, am retrieving data from db and trying to display it in FlatList in react-native.

But, it displying undefined in list.. and lots of rows are coming in FlatList with the value 'undefined'.

Below is the render() method of my component :

```
 render() {
    var A = realm.objects('Student_Info');
    var myJSON = JSON.stringify(A);

    return (

      <View style={styles.MainContainer}>

        <TextInput 
              placeholder="Student Name"
              style = { styles.TextInputStyle } 
              underlineColorAndroid = "transparent" 
              onChangeText = { ( text ) => { this.setState({ Student_Name: text })} } 
            />

        <TextInput  
              placeholder="Class"
              style = { styles.TextInputStyle } 
              underlineColorAndroid = "transparent" 
              onChangeText = { ( text ) => { this.setState({ Student_Class: text })} } 
            />

        <TextInput 
              placeholder="Subject"
              style = { styles.TextInputStyle } 
              underlineColorAndroid = "transparent" 
              onChangeText = { ( text ) => { this.setState({ Student_Subject: text })} } 
            />
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.add_Student} activeOpacity={0.7} style={styles.button} >
          <Text style={styles.TextStyle}> Make Student Entry </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <Text style={{marginTop: 10}}>{myJSON}</Text>

        <FlatList      
          //data={this.state.dataSource}
          data={myJSON}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this._flatListItemSeparator}
          renderItem={({ item }) =>
            <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }} >
              <Text style={styles.textView}>{"Student Name : "+item.student_id}</Text>
            </View>
          }
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        />
      </View>  
     );
```

What might be the issue ?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

The json data i got from my db is as below :

```
{"0":{"student_id":1,"student_name":"Ashish","student_class":"React","student_subject":"React native"},"1":{"student_id":2,"student_name":"Ashish1","student_class":"React1","student_subject":"React native1"},"2":{"student_id":3,"student_name":"","student_class":"","student_subject":""},"3":{"student_id":4,"student_name":"","student_class":"","student_subject":""}}
```

Schema was reated using :

```
 realm = new Realm({
      schema: [{
        name: 'Student_Info',
        properties:
        {
          student_id: { type: 'int', default: 0 },
          student_name: 'string',
          student_class: 'string',
          student_subject: 'string'
        }
      }]
    });
```

Comment: first check whether you are getting your data from db

Comment: yes getting in myJSON... as {"0":{"student_id":1,"student_name":"xyz",}......

Comment: displyed data coming from db and converting to to json here in this line :    <Text style={{marginTop: 10}}>{myJSON}</Text>

Comment: can you share your full JSON in question please and validate it here https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: {"0:{"student_id":1,"student_name":"xyz","student_class":"class1","student_subject":"subject1"}}

Comment: try `data={myJSON[0]}` and see ... in btw a double quotes is missing in `0`

Comment: trying this am getting only one record. But the value is Student Name : undefined...

Comment: that is why i asked to share you whole JSON.

Comment: @AravindS Edited question. Added Json in question. pls. check.

Comment: Check this https://codesandbox.io/s/3qr4qqkvzq... Data should be an array in flatlist

Comment: you are great @AravindS sir.

Comment: I will add it as answer...upvote and accept the answer if it helped..Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One key thing which you missed is, flatlist `data` prop should be an array. So I updated your JSON like

```
let myJSON = [
      {
        "0": {
          student_id: 1,
          student_name: "Ashish",
          student_class: "React",
          student_subject: "React native"
        },
        "1": {
          student_id: 2,
          student_name: "Ashish1",
          student_class: "React1",
          student_subject: "React native1"
        },
        "2": {
          student_id: 3,
          student_name: "",
          student_class: "",
          student_subject: ""
        },
        "3": {
          student_id: 4,
          student_name: "",
          student_class: "",
          student_subject: ""
        }
      }
    ];
```

and use `Object.values(myJSON)` to get array of object of your data.Use the flatlist as shownbelow

```
<View>
        <FlatList
          //data={this.state.dataSource}
          data={myJSON}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "column" }}>
              <Text style={styles.textView}>{item[0].student_id}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.textView}>{item[1].student_id}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.textView}>{item[2].student_id}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.textView}>{item[3].student_id}</Text>
            </View>
          )}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        />
      </View>
```

Answer (score 1):

As  @AravindS shown in his demo. That the Flat list accepts an array as data, So first you need to convert your myJSON from {{}} to [{}] array of Objects.

```
render() {
   var A = realm.objects('Student_Info');
   // Remove This line    var myJSON = JSON.stringify(A);

   // Add this line 
   var studentsDetail = Object.values(A);
       ....

   // Assign studentsDetail to data prop of flat list

   <FlatList      
      data={studentsDetail}
         ...
 // Rest of code
```

Comment: no sir its giving Objects are not valid as a React Child.

Comment: Please remove the JSON.stringify(A) from the code. After removing it is working perfectly.